# get user time and convert them to PST

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm stuck on this problem

to get a user time i would just do

```
var getUserDateAndTime = new Date();
```

How would I convert that date time into the PST depending on where they are (EST or GMT) with day light savings in mind.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to get the timezone offset from the client:

```
var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

Then you need the PST timezone offset and you can calculate it

ClientTime - ClientOffset + PSTOffset = current PST time

Comment: And how are you factoring in daylight savings here?

Comment: getTimezoneOffset returns a different value in daylight savings, thats why it will work. If you you want to read more about it : [link](http://javascript.about.com/library/bldst.htm)

Comment: var offset = 420;
        var pst = new Date() - new Date().getTimezoneOffset() + offset;
        var currentDate = new Date(pst); wont convert to PST

Comment: Here is a short example : http://jsfiddle.net/F5hCX/ you forgot that the offset is in minutes and the time in milliseconds!

Comment: Sorry in my example i made a mistake ... you have to know that Date.toUTCString() is returning you (ClientTime - ClientOffset) the current GMT+0 time... so you only have to add PSTOffset. But getTimezoneOffset() returns the value you have to add to your local time to get the GMT+0 time, and you want the other way so you have to subtract the PSTOffset... reworked example : http://jsfiddle.net/F5hCX/1/