# Converting JavaScript time to multiple time zones without moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I am trying to convert current JavaScript time into different time zones based on few conditions.

Times zones to which I need to convert are "PT", "PST" etc.

So, in order to do that I need to convert the current date 
into "PT" or other time zones conditionally. Most of the answers on [stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22493924/get-user-time-and-convert-them-to-pst) direct to use "getTimezoneOffset()". But I didn't get any luck.

```
var now = new Date();
var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

How can I get offset of "PST", "PT" or any other time zones?

```
var convertedTime = now.toTimeString().split(' ')[0];
```

Comment: java script. not java

Comment: Use  [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) instead of custom conversions

Comment: I can't use any other js except customization of java script only.

Comment: But that is using moment.js and I can't use that.

Comment: There are other answers to that question which do not use momentjs. For instance [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10088053/5459839). I am sure you'll be able to find out the offset expressed in minutes you need to pass to that function.

Comment: yes. this is now giving me some different time. I assume its the local time to that city whose offset is passed to the function. But the toLocaleString is converting the actual time to AM or PM. for eg:
nd = Mon May 22 2017 23:13:36 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

If time to that city is "Mon May 22 2017 23:13:36".

ToLocale would convert it to 5/22/2017 11:13:36 PM.

But don't need in AM or PM. just need 23:13:36 so I am not using Tolocale here